# How to rename files on Windows using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have tried to use **OS Process Sampler** to rename a file on my desktop, this was my configuration:

- **Command**: ren
- **Working directory**: Path to desktop
- **Command parameter 1**: name of the file
- **Command parameter 2**: the name i want to change to

error on view result tree:

```
Exception occurred whilst executing system call: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ren" (in directory "Working directory i specified"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I can work with any other solution, if it cant be done using OS process sampler

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show how you configured your component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE

**OS Sampler Config**

Here is the config you need to set up in `OS Process Sampler`

**Command :** `cmd`

**Command Parameters:**

Add each value in a separate row.

`/C
ren C:\Test\Oldfilename.txt newfilename.txt`

### Alternate Solution

Here is the code which renames the file using `BeanShell PostProcessor`

```
try {

String oldfile = "C:\\TestingTools\\apache-jmeter-3.2\\apache-jmeter-3.2\\bin\\test.txt";
File file = new File(oldfile);
File newfile = new File("C:\\TestingTools\\apache-jmeter-3.2\\apache-jmeter-3.2\\bin\\test123.txt");

boolean success = file.renameTo(newfile);
if (success)
log.info("file renamed successfully");             
}

catch (Throwable e) {
    log.error("Error in Beanshell",e);
}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call [rename command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490987.aspx) directly, you need to do it via [CMD interpreter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490880.aspx) like:

```
cmd /c rename file1 file2
```

The relevant OS Process Sampler configuration will look like:

[image: JMeter OS Process Sampler Rename File]

One parameter - one line.

Check out [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article for more information regarding the different approaches of running 3rd-party apps within the bounds of a JMeter test.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use BeanShell Sampler to perform this task.**

> BeanShell is one of the most advanced JMeter built-in components. It
>   supports Java syntax and extends it with scripting features like loose
>   types, commands, and method closures. If your test case is uncommon
>   and implementation via embedded JMeter components becomes tricky or
>   even impossible, BeanShell can be an excellent option to achieve your
>   objectives.

To perform this first declare Jmeter variables in your Test Plan

[image: Test Plan Interface]

After wards Add a **Thread Group,BeanShell Sampler,HTTP Request,View Result Tree** [*preference*]

```
Below Code is the Sample BeanShell Code which I implemented.

try{
int count=0;
String renamedFile = "";
File imageFile;
String image ="E:\\MCMS\\USR1\\issue"+(int) (Math.random()*1000000000)+".PNG";

if(vars.get("counter").equals("A"))
{
imageFile = new File("E:\\MCMS\\USR1\\issue657327357.PNG");
//vars.put("fileName",imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
log.info("First File Identification");
log.info("First File Name : "+imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
vars.put("counter","B");
}
else
{
imageFile = new File(vars.get("nextFile"));
log.info("Next File Iterations");
log.info("Current System file : "+imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
}
File imageFile2 = new File(image);
log.info("System Ram gerated File :"+imageFile2.getAbsolutePath());
log.info("System is giong to replace ram generated file with current system file :");
if (imageFile.renameTo(imageFile2)) 
{
vars.put("nextFile", ""+imageFile2.getAbsolutePath());
log.info("Conversion successful");
log.info("Assigning the new file name to the jmeter variable");
vars.put("fileName",imageFile2.getAbsolutePath());
log.info(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
log.info(imageFile2.getAbsolutePath());
} 
else
{
log.info("Rename failed");
log.info("I failed but the file in the directory is"+imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
}
}
catch(Exception e){
log.info("Exception Occured"+e);
}
```

**Do note that You cannot use it to be used by many users by just increasing 
Number of Threads (users) by the thread group, as jmeter is not implemented that way.
Technically then all threads will try to change one file name at once which it will not work.
The solution to that is create a folder structure for the count of users you trying to perform the test and set the path to each respective folder mapping the thread count.**

as illustrated in the below image

[image]